# Is there any issue with precaching script type module?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am working on a PWA side project, so when I precache the script type module, the browser cannot fetch the script in offline mode, but when I use another strategy for caching ie. "on network response; return from cache if match is found or add to cache" it works fine in offline mode.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
    e.respondWith(
        caches.open(cacheVersion)
            .then(cache => cache.match(e.request)
                .then(res => res || fetch(e.request)
                    .then(res => {
                        cache.put(e.request, res.clone());
                        return res;
                    }).catch(err => {
                        console.log('Fetch failed');
                    })
                )
            )
    );
});
```

Browser fails to fetch the script when I use the following fetch strategy

```
e.respondWith(
        fetch(e.request)
            .catch(() => caches.match(e.request))
    );
```

Here's how I am precaching my assets while using this strategy

```
cache.addAll([
    '/',
    '/style.css',
    '/src/app.js',
    '/src/router/index.js',
    '/src/router/Route.js',
    '/src/router/Router.js',
    '/src/views/home.js',
    '/src/views/offline.js',
    '/src/views/post.js'
]);
```

These are all the javascript module files, where app.js is the main entry file

```html
<script src="src/app.js" type="module"></script>
```

If you need to have a look at the complete source code you can find it in the link below
https://github.com/vijitail/headless-wordpress-pwa

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/12/modulepreload